How can decades-long ageless sleep work without either warping time or allowing biological immortality?
I am working on a setting with interstellar travel but no faster-than-light travel; since generation ships require almost perfect recycling technology and are unlikely to be socially and culturally stable, this setting features technology with the ability to hold individual organisms in a state of suspended animation in which they can never be conscious but do not experience any biological aging.
The question that I find myself asking is how to avoid this technology having other applications which do not fit with the aesthetic of the setting; the simplest explanation for such technology would be the ability to create areas of space where time does not pass, but giving the setting time-manipulation technology would radically alter it in a way I do not want. The next most common explanation given for such technology would most likely be that this is some advanced form of cryonics, but this would require the ability to revive vitrified people, which would effectively create immortality. Simple induced prolonged sleep or coma would not stop aging and, therefore, does not meet the criteria.
My question then, is this: How can a technology exist which would allow decades-long ageless unconsciousness without warping time or allowing a conscious human to not age?
Answers should not rely on anything overtly supernatural or defying of known physical laws, but answers assuming some undiscovered but plausible phenomenon are fine.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

OK, you are asking for a solution to a problem that doesn't exist in the scenario you have outlined, or if it does exist you haven't adequately outlined what the problem is, there is nothing in freezing someone that plausibly leads to immortality, voting to close, needs detail and clarity.


some advanced form of cryonics, but this would require the ability to
revive vitrified people, which would effectively create immortality.

Why? This assumes that the cryopreservation technology is very crude, while the revival technology is extremely advanced, which is a strange order of development. Devising a cryo-pod/fluid that does not cause ice-crystal damage to human cells is significantly easier than devising nanotechnology that could repair such damage.
Assuming the technological progress is linear (no alien gods dropping nanotech on our lap etc), a very simple bio-nano infusion that prevents freeze-burn is going to be invented decades before intelligent nanotech that could repair freeze-burned cells.
Simple, no-freeze cryonics that use advanced chemistry to cool our cells without freezing them would not magically translate to immortality, though of course it would lead to technically longer lifespans (ex: live for a 80 years, but "sleep" for 800 between your 35 and 36 year of active life).

just add risks and cost
Pick whatever semi-scientific justification for suspended animation you like out of the sci fi catalog. Cryo, drugs, digitization and reincarnation, etc.
Make it expensive. Say, ten million dollars a Sleep: a drop in the bucket for an interstellar space mission, but out of reach for almost every other budget.
Add a risk of irreversible harm or death that increases the more you use it, especially if you weren't in top physical condition to start with. Again, not a big deal for an interstellar mission, which is incredibly dangerous to start with and almost certainly a one way trip. But if one in twenty healthy young Sleepers gets severe injury or death every decade on their first Sleep, and the likelihood of death gets higher with the number of Sleeps, nobody is going to use it for future tourism unless they step through the wrong door trying to deliver Pizza Express.
You could also add a special requirement to use it at all, so that most people physically can't Sleep. Perhaps only people with a certain rare genetic resilience to a certain kind of drug can use the Sleep, or it doesn't work at all if you mass more than 40 kg, etc.

The only problem I have with digitization is the memory of attending a software demonstration at Cadence Design Systems in the late 1990s when the tech holding the one and only hard drive containing the working, compiled prototype tripped (I kid you not) and the drive broke open on the floor. That memory will forever cause me fear over digitization!

@jbh I doubt that digitizing a mind (even for storage, and as a copy, not a continuation) is metaphysically possible, but it's borderline plausible which is good enough for fiction!

Energy requirements and inspections.
The nearer you try to get to the speed of light, the greater the time dilation according to the mathematical relationship:
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
Where gamma is the time-dilation factor.
Its mass increases correspondingly, and the energy needed to accelerate it in turn increases alarmingly.
This leaves your very finite ships, with finite energy supplies with a limited top-speed. If it also requires energy to maintain the cryo-systems at peek efficiency, then that's a double limitation.
You could have laws enforced at ports such that a strict limit is placed on the fuel a ship is allowed to depart with. The cryo-system, engines and "tanks" would all be subject to strict inspections - with the cryo-systems needing to conform to a standard whereby they "wake-up" the occupant after a strict time-limit - this would be sealed, recorded in incorruptible ship's computer systems, and correspond to an internal chronometer within the individuals frozen (fitted at birth and recording everything the body experiences, these would be tough to tamper with as even the slightest scar would be detectable). These would be checked on departure and arrival at the registered destination.
Any variance from the proscribed time allowances would prompt the convening of a court of review, which would have the power to summarily confiscate the life of anyone found in violation of these strict regulations.
As to specifics, the Lorentz calculator, gives a gamma of 1.1547005 for when traveling at 1/2 the speed of light (or 51.96 minutes passes on-ship relative flight time for every hour at the departure lounge). A gamma of 3.202563 at 0.95 the speed of light - corresponding to time passing at roughly a third of the speed of at the departure lounge, but set the acceptable limits to suite your story. (Remembering to compensate for relative velocity of departure and arrival star-systems, of course.)

Card used this to get Ender to the future in Speaker for the Dead, so it has pedigree, whether it's practicable or not!

I'd been meaning to read those, since they never bothered to finish making the films! @gs

I enjoyed the whose series. Although it is unlike the YA military sci fi vibe of Ender's Game, and very Orson Scott Card-y in places.
